# Navigation Bar not visible in simulator but visible in storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Additional info >>

Just noticed that in my application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: i've got this

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]  init];
viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"frontScreen"];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Is this part of the problem?

R

=================

Hi I'm developing an app in storyboard.
I'm using the publicly available `SWRevealViewController` to manage some navigation bar reveal menus.

I've set up a simple `UIViewController`, lets call it `WelcomeViewController`. I've dragged a segue from the `RevealViewController` to my new `WelcomeViewController` and then I've embed in a `Navigation Controller`. To the navigation bar I've added a menu reveal button.

All looks good in the storyboard, however when I run in the simulator the navigation bar isn't there.
I've added

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

in the `viewWillAppear` method - to no avail.

I should mention that I've got an entire branch of viewcontrollers and functionality already coming off the revealviewcontroller with no problems.

Any help. I've search stack overflow but found nothing that matches my specific problems. All advice gratefully received.

R

Comment: this is not sufficient to understand the problem..it is clear that you are committing some error in somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The storyboard entry point needs to be from the navigation controller and not the main view controller. That should make the navigation toolbar show up in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

in the view controller's viewDidLoad method

Comment: Does the navigation bar definitely have a title? I know that prompts do not show it their text is null

Comment: There's no navigation bar appearing at all. There's one in the storyboard. I've not set a title in the storyboard. Should I?

Comment: Set a title for the navigation bar in your storyboard. Also delete all that code in your app delegate method and in your storyboard tick the "is initial view controller" box in its properties.  In your apps info.plist file also see if there is a key called "status bar is initially hidden" and set that to false

Answer (score 0):

Because the default navigation bar property translucent is set to YES
you can set it to NO on your second view page on viewDidLoad.

```
navi.translucent = NO;
```